# Figuring out extension methods source

Tags: c#

This week I started using c#. One of the features I am struggling with is extension methods; it makes the code look nice and readable, but I'm having problems with figuring out where they come from. Is there some easy way to do this?

I started with a ReactiveUI example on the main page, but the examples didn't provide the `using`statements. So Visual Studio started to complain that methods didn't exists. In the end I figured out I had to be `using System.Reactive.Disposables`.

And BTW; that's another thing: `System` is not a protected namespace name? Anybody can produce packages using the `System` namespace?

Comment: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/57294/adding-to-the-system-namespace-in-c

Comment: If you put your cursor on the extension method and press `ctrl+.`, Visual Studio is pretty good at figuring out what you need to import to get that extension method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are more and more scenarios where Visual Studio can find the source and suggest it to the coder.

You can check if VS has a good suggestion (sometimes there can be multiple) by:

- hovering over the method's name and selecting *Show potential fixes*
  [image]

  OR
- pressing Ctrl+. (dot) 
  [image]

If the suggestion is not there (or is incorrect) the problem is often solved with a search in your chosen search engine).